# Why are there two "Smaller & Smaller"s?

Tags: 20th-century, art, netherlands

So M.C. Escher created a piece of art called "Smaller & Smaller". The problem is, when you look it up, two similar but non-identical pieces of art come up:

[image]

and

[image]

The color difference isn't a big deal, since Escher is known for making copies with different colors. The problem is the other, non-color differences (look at the corners in particular).

So, why are there two of them? Are both made by M.C. Escher, or is one a fake?

Comment: Artists do test pieces and often these survive and sometimes they do variations on a theme. I'd think this is more of a question about visual arts than about history.

Comment: @KillingTime is there a place I could migrate it, perhaps?

Comment: Try asking this on [here](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "Smaller & Smaller" is the first one; I'm not sure what the second one came from, but perhaps Wikiart misidentified it. Perhaps it's an earlier draft or a later variation?

Comment: It isn't uncommon for artists to have multiple similar works that have the same name.  For instance, there are [four versions of Munch's "The Scream"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scream)

Comment: @Jake art history does not appear to be on topic there.